# Why doesn't Laravel show the file name when debugging?

Tags: php, debugging, laravel, laravel-5, homestead

I'm using Laravel 5, Homestead, Vim 7.4, and Linux Mint 17. I've tried both `debug=true` and `debug=false` in app.php. When I get an error, Laravel shows a crazy hash string instead of the file name. I can't find info on this anywhere online, and i'm not sure if it's Laravel, Homestead, not having xdebug or something, or maybe the way Vim saves files.

FWIW, I know this happened in a blade view file.

[image]

Comment: The crazy hash you see is the cached version of your view file. You can double click the hash to see the full path of said file, but that's still just the path to the cached version. Turning off view caching will give you actual file names. You can also use something like [filp/Whoops](https://github.com/filp/whoops) to handle errors for you, which will give you better information.

Comment: I will add that, even with [filp/Whoops](https://github.com/filp/whoops), errors in view files will still refer to the cached path, however the handler displays a snippet of the code as reference, which is usually enough to identify the file in question. Besides disabling view caching (which is tricky, I should mention), there's really not much you can do about those path hashes. That's just how Laravel behaves when it comes to views, unfortunately.

Comment: I would have posted this as an answer, but I didn't feel right answering with, essentially, "too bad".

Comment: That is too bad, but knowing it's an error in the view does help narrow it down a lot.